# NoNodeAvailableException[None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{IfVRlxsUSDGVyFzl_Rabkg}{10.10.10.109}{10.10.10.109:9300}]]

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I've installed `elasticsearch 5.0.2`(latest version) on my `server(10.10.10.109)` and trying to create Transport client from java, i'm unable to connect and getting the "NoNodeAvalible exception". I've included the same version of `elasticsearch` maven dependency in my project. But didn't getting to know where am i going wrong.

```
TransportClient client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(Settings.EMPTY)
        .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("10.10.10.109"), 9300));
```

Here is my `elasticsearch.yml` file

```
#
        # NOTE: Elasticsearch comes with reasonable defaults for most settings.
        #       Before you set out to tweak and tune the configuration, make sure you
        #       understand what are you trying to accomplish and the consequences.
        #
        # The primary way of configuring a node is via this file. This template lists
        # the most important settings you may want to configure for a production cluster.
        #
        # Please see the documentation for further information on configuration options:
        # <http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-configuration.html>
        #
        # ---------------------------------- Cluster -----------------------------------
        #
        # Use a descriptive name for your cluster:
        #
        #cluster.name: my-application
        #
        # ------------------------------------ Node ------------------------------------
        #
        # Use a descriptive name for the node:
        #
        #node.name: node-1
        #
        # Add custom attributes to the node:
        #
        #node.attr.rack: r1
        #
        # ----------------------------------- Paths ------------------------------------
        #
        # Path to directory where to store the data (separate multiple locations by comma):
        #
        #path.data: /path/to/data
        #
        # Path to log files:
        #
        #path.logs: /path/to/logs
        #
        # ----------------------------------- Memory -----------------------------------
        #
        # Lock the memory on startup:
        #
        #bootstrap.memory_lock: true
        #
        # Make sure that the heap size is set to about half the memory available
        # on the system and that the owner of the process is allowed to use this
        # limit.
        #
        # Elasticsearch performs poorly when the system is swapping the memory.
        #
        # ---------------------------------- Network -----------------------------------
        #
        # Set the bind address to a specific IP (IPv4 or IPv6):
        #
        network.host: 10.10.10.109
        #
        # Set a custom port for HTTP:
        #
        #http.port: 9200
        #
        # For more information, see the documentation at:
        # <http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-network.html>
        #
        # --------------------------------- Discovery ----------------------------------
        #
        # Pass an initial list of hosts to perform discovery when new node is started:
        # The default list of hosts is ["127.0.0.1", "[::1]"]
        #
        #discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["host1", "host2"]
        #
        # Prevent the "split brain" by configuring the majority of nodes (total number of nodes / 2 + 1):
        #
        #discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 3
        #
        # For more information, see the documentation at:
        # <http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-discovery.html>
        #
        # ---------------------------------- Gateway -----------------------------------
        #
        # Block initial recovery after a full cluster restart until N nodes are started:
        #
        #gateway.recover_after_nodes: 3
        #
        # For more information, see the documentation at:
        # <http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-gateway.html>
        #
        # ---------------------------------- Various -----------------------------------
        #
        # Disable starting multiple nodes on a single system:
        #
        #node.max_local_storage_nodes: 1
        #
        # Require explicit names when deleting indices:
        #
        #action.destructive_requires_name: true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer, my server firewall was blocking the 9300 port, that is why i'm unable to connect. 
Thanks.